# null pointer exception in JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

On Glassfish server, I am new in using JPA injection: when I try to query the database (retrieve the full list of Company objects), I get the following error:

```
2015-08-08T23:21:43.810+0200|Grave: Error Rendering View[/secure/searchCompany.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /secure/searchCompany.xhtml @38,59 value="#{searchCompanyBean.companies}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.getValue(UISequence.java:179)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.createExtendedDataModel(UISequence.java:113)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTableBase.createExtendedDataModel(UIDataTableBase.java:211)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptor.java:280)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.ExtendedDataTableRenderer.doEncodeChildren(ExtendedDataTableRenderer.java:720)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:158)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:282)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:183)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:180)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sdzee.dao.CompanyDao.searchCompanies(CompanyDao.java:30)
    at com.sdzee.bean.SearchCompanyBean.getCompanies(SearchCompanyBean.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    ... 63 more

2015-08-08T23:21:43.813+0200|Infos: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sdzee.dao.CompanyDao.searchCompanies(CompanyDao.java:30)
    at com.sdzee.bean.SearchCompanyBean.getCompanies(SearchCompanyBean.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.getValue(UISequence.java:179)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.createExtendedDataModel(UISequence.java:113)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTableBase.createExtendedDataModel(UIDataTableBase.java:211)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptor.java:280)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.ExtendedDataTableRenderer.doEncodeChildren(ExtendedDataTableRenderer.java:720)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:158)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:282)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:183)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:180)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-08-08T23:21:43.814+0200|Avertissement: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sdzee.dao.CompanyDao.searchCompanies(CompanyDao.java:30)
    at com.sdzee.bean.SearchCompanyBean.getCompanies(SearchCompanyBean.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.getValue(UISequence.java:179)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.createExtendedDataModel(UISequence.java:113)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTableBase.createExtendedDataModel(UIDataTableBase.java:211)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptor.java:280)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.ExtendedDataTableRenderer.doEncodeChildren(ExtendedDataTableRenderer.java:720)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:158)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:282)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:183)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:180)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In CompanyDao.java file, the line 30 is :

```
Query requete = em.createQuery( JPQL_SEARCH_COMPANIES );
```

The CompanyDao.java file contains:

```
@Stateless
public class CompanyDao {
    private static final String JPQL_SEARCH_COMPANIES = "SELECT c FROM Company c where c.name like :companyName and c.city like :companyCity";
    private static final String PARAM_COMPANY_NAME = "companyName";
    private static final String PARAM_COMPANY_CITY = "companyCity";

    // Injection of the manager, which manages the connexion with the Database
    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "bdd_sdzee_PU" )
    private EntityManager em;

    // Search all the companies

    public List<Company> searchCompanies(String companyName, String companyCity) throws DAOException {
        List<Company> listCompanies = null;
        Query requete = em.createQuery( JPQL_SEARCH_COMPANIES );
        requete.setParameter( PARAM_COMPANY_NAME, "%"+companyName+"%");
        requete.setParameter( PARAM_COMPANY_CITY, "%"+companyCity+"%");
        try {
            listCompanies = requete.getResultList();
        } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
            return null;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw new DAOException( e );
        }
        return listCompanies;
    }   
}
```

The searchCompany.xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="/resources/template/layout.xhtml"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <style type="text/css">
            .rf-edt-r-sel{
                 font-weight: normal;
                 background-color: rgb(95,180,251);
            }
        </style>
        <h:form>
            <rich:panel style="width:1024px">
                <h:panelGrid columns="5" border="0" cellpadding="0" styleClass="panelGridCenter" columnClasses="columnDefaultClass, columnDefaultClass, column200Class, columnDefaultClass, columnDefaultClass">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['company']} : " for="companyName" style="text-align:right"/>
                    <rich:autocomplete value="#{searchCompanyBean.companyName}" id="companyName" mode="lazyClient" autocompleteList="#{searchCompanyBean.listOfCompanyNames}" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
                    <h:outputText />
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['city']} : " for="companyCity" style="text-align:right"/>
                    <rich:autocomplete value="#{searchCompanyBean.companyCity}" id="companyCity" mode="lazyClient" autocompleteList="#{searchCompanyBean.listOfCompanyCities}" style="vertical-align: middle" />
                </h:panelGrid>      
                <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
                    <a4j:commandButton value="#{msg['search']}" action="#{searchCompanyBean.searchCompanies}" render="@form" execute="@form" />
                </h:panelGroup>     
            </rich:panel>
            <rich:panel style="width:1024px">
                <rich:extendedDataTable id="table" 
                        value="#{searchCompanyBean.companies}" 
                        var="company" frozenColumns="1"
                        sortPriority="#{sortCompanyBean.sortPriorities}"
                        selectionMode="multiple"
                        style="height:500px; width:1000px;"
                        selection="#{searchCompanyBean.selectionCompanies}">
                    <a4j:ajax execute="@form" 
                        event="selectionchange" 
                        listener="#{searchCompanyBean.selectionListener}"
                        render="details"/>
                    <rich:column width="150px"
                        sortBy="#{company.name}"
                        sortOrder="#{sortCompanyBean.sortsOrders['name']}"
                        sortType="custom"
                        headerClass="headerClass1">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <a4j:commandLink execute="@this" value="#{msg['name']}" render="table"
                                                 action="#{sortCompanyBean.sort}">
                                    <f:param name="sortProperty" value="name"/>
                                </a4j:commandLink>
                                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/default/images/icons/arrow_up.png"
                                                rendered="#{sortCompanyBean.sortsOrders['name']=='descending'}"/>
                                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/default/images/icons/arrow_down.png"
                                                rendered="#{sortCompanyBean.sortsOrders['name']=='ascending'}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </f:facet>                  
                        #{company.name}
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="500px"
                        sortBy="#{company.comment}"
                        sortOrder="#{sortCompanyBean.sortsOrders['comment']}"
                        sortType="custom"
                        headerClass="headerClass1">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <a4j:commandLink execute="@this" value="#{msg['comment']}" render="table"
                                                 action="#{sortCompanyBean.sort}">
                                    <f:param name="sortProperty" value="comment"/>
                                </a4j:commandLink>
                                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/default/images/icons/arrow_up.png"
                                                rendered="#{sortCompanyBean.sortsOrders['comment']=='descending'}"/>
                                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/default/images/icons/arrow_down.png"
                                                rendered="#{sortCompanyBean.sortsOrders['comment']=='ascending'}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </f:facet>                  
                        #{company.comment}
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:extendedDataTable>
                <rich:contextMenu target="table" mode="ajax">
                    <rich:menuItem
                                    label="#{msg['edit']}"
                                    actionListener="#{maPopup.ouvrir}"
                                    mode="ajax"
                                    icon="/resources/default/images/icons/edit_detail.png"/>
                </rich:contextMenu>
            </rich:panel>
            <rich:messages />
        </h:form>    
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The SearchCompanyBean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped

public class SearchCompanyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // Injection de notre EJB (Session Bean Stateless)
    @EJB
    private @Inject CompanyService das;

    private CompanyDao companyDao = new CompanyDao();
    private Company company;
    private List<Company> companies;
    private List<String> listOfCompanyNames = null;
    private List<String> listOfCompanyCities = null;
    private String companyName;
    private String companyCity;
    private String selectionMode = "multiple";
    private Collection<Object> selection = null;

    private List<Company> selectionCompanies = null;
    private Company selectionCompany = new Company();

    public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        UIExtendedDataTable dataTable = (UIExtendedDataTable)event.getComponent();
        selectionCompanies = new ArrayList<Company>();
        Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();
        for (Object selectionKey : selection) {
            dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey);
//            if (dataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
                selectionCompanies.add((Company)dataTable.getRowData());
//            }
        }
        dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);
    }

    public Collection<Object> getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(Collection<Object> selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public Company getSelectionCompany() {
        if (selectionCompanies == null || selectionCompanies.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return selectionCompanies.get(0);
    }

    public void setSelectionCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public List<Company> getSelectionCompanies() {
        return selectionCompanies;
    }

    public void setSelectionCompanies(List<Company> selectionCompanies) {
        this.selectionCompanies = selectionCompanies;
    }

    public void searchCompanies(){
        companies = companyDao.searchCompanies(companyName, companyCity);
    }

    public Company getCompany(){
        return company;
    }

    public List<Company> getCompanies(){
        if (companies==null){
            companies = companyDao.searchCompanies("",""); // By default, when displaying the page, all the Companies are listed
        }
        return companies;
    }    
}
```

persistence.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bdd_sdzee_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysql_resource</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.sdzee.entities.Utilisateur</class>       
        <class>com.sdzee.entities.Company</class>       
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties> 
     </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SearchCompanyBean you create your own object of the CompanyDao:

```
private CompanyDao companyDao = new CompanyDao();
```

However, in this case field injections won't happen, since the container doesn't know about them (like the PersistenceContext).

So to enable the injection, you have to inject the CompanyDao in the SearchCompanyBean to let the container handle the lifecycle of the object and the dependencies (like you did with the CompanyService).

Answer (score 2):

If your post contains the full `CompanyDao` class, then the following error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sdzee.dao.CompanyDao.searchCompanies(CompanyDao.java:30)
```

is because you are using the `em` variable while you forgot to initialize it.

```
Query requete = em.createQuery( JPQL_SEARCH_COMPANIES ); // Error --> "em" still null
```